# C# .NET web application Web Form message other Web Form on data changed

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms, sendmessage

Alright, here's my situation. I've been looking on the internet but I can't find anything to tackle this problem.

I got two different Web applications in C# .NET. The first one (Let's call it application A) is to create, insert, update and delete data to the database. And the second one (Application B) is just to display information on a screen from the database but it can update a few small things on it's own, the single page is divided in different sections with each an update panel because certain things need to update more often than others.

What I want is, if application A changes any data to the database, I want applicaiton B to update its update panels, so I want application A to send a message of some kind to application B. Currently the updatepanels update every x seconds which is horrible for the servers.

Note that application B can have different clients, which each having their own unique data.

Does anyone have an idea of how to tackle this problem and what techniques can be used for this?

Comment: You look for ready to use solution on internet - rather than think a scenario to implement your request. There are many examples if you search on google.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, for the web, the server doesn't do anything until the client asks it to. In this case, it's not the client that's asking, it's another server. If you want Application B to update the client without the client asking for it, you're going to have to do a WebSocket or some other push system between Application B and its client.

To send data from Application A to Application B, you'll need to use one of a couple different IPC (interprocess communication) tools. The easiest would probably be to set up a UDP or a TCP socket between Application A and Application B.

Answer (score 0):

how about a CORS request ?

write an AJAX call to the App B from App A such that whenever the update process complete it should send the call (you can us Webmethod of course for achieving this) and in the application B you can update the Panel from the function

Comment: I have never heard of CORS before, I'm gonna read into it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

SqlDependency is a special .NET class which lets you subscribe for an event and later the subscribed command gets notification from SQLServer 
from 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953(v=vs.110).aspx